# Binding a function to multiple sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.join('myRoom');
    if(condition){
        bindFunctions();
    }

});
```

Let's say `condition` is true when the 4th socket connects. The code below successfully binds a `.on` handler to all the sockets in `myRoom`.

```
bindFunctions(){
    for(var socketId in io.sockets.adapter.rooms["myRoom"]){

        var socket = io.sockets.connected[socketId];

        socket.on('my event',function(submit){
            console.log(socket.myVariable);
            //This is always the same property, no matter who calls this function.      

        }); 
    }
}
```

However, when `'my event'` fires, regardless of which client triggered it, the `socket` object is always the 4th socket that connected. It is always the socket that called `bindFunctions`. I would have thought that the handler socket should be the same as the socket inside the function.

So I have two questions:

Why is the socket inside the `'my event'` function the socket that called `bindFunctions` instead of the socket that fired the event?

What can I do instead to be able to access properties of the socket that called `'my event'` whilst inside the function?

Comment: why aren't you binding the function directly to the socket once it connects? like `io.on('connection', function(socket) { socket.join('myroom'); socket.on('my event', function ...) }` and then you can check your condition inside the binded function... that way you don't have to loop over your sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because although you're doing `var socket = io.sockets.connected[socketId];` inside the loop, [in Javascript, the `var` keyword is function scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), and not block scoped.

Under the guts, what really happens is:

```
bindFunctions(){
    var socket;
    for(var socketId in io.sockets.adapter.rooms["myRoom"]){

        socket = io.sockets.connected[socketId];

        socket.on('my event',function(submit){
            console.log(socket.myVariable);
            //This is always the same property, no matter who calls this function.      

        }); 
    }
}
```

So, since your event will happen later, your `socket` variable is always the last one set.

To prevent this behavior, if using Node.js version > 4.0.0, you can use [`const` instead of `var`, because it's block scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const). But in Node.js, to be able to use `const` and `let` keywords block-scoped, you must put `'use strict';` in the begining of your function, e.g:

```
bindFunctions(){
    'use strict';
    for(var socketId in io.sockets.adapter.rooms["myRoom"]){

        const socket = io.sockets.connected[socketId];

        socket.on('my event',function(submit){
            console.log(socket.myVariable);
            //This is always the same property, no matter who calls this function.      

        }); 
    }
}
```

---

Another way of solving your problem is by creating an IIFE, so you always pass the current variable to the event, e.g:

```
bindFunctions(){
    for(var socketId in io.sockets.adapter.rooms["myRoom"]){

        var socket = io.sockets.connected[socketId];

        (function(socket) {
            socket.on('my event',function(submit){
                console.log(socket.myVariable);
            });
        })(socket);
    }
}
```

Doing that, the `socket` variable inside the IIFE will always refer to the object passed as parameter, and you'll get your desired behavior.

---

You can also use `Object.keys` combined with `Array.prototype.forEach` instead of `for...in` loop:

```
bindFunctions(){
    var room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms["myRoom"];
    Object.keys(room).forEach(function(key) {
        var socketId = room[key];

        var socket = io.sockets.connected[socketId];

        socket.on('my event',function(submit){
            console.log(socket.myVariable);    
        }); 
    });
}
```

Doing that, you're creating a new context each iteration, since it's a callback function being called, and you won't have problems with function scoping.

Comment: probably best to use `let`, no? Doesn't `const` represent an unchanging variable?

Comment: @JonathanBrooks since he's creating the `socket` inside the loop, and never changing it, theoretically is a `const` variable. If you use some linter, e.g: ESLint, it will warn that although you're using `let`, you never changes its value.

Comment: Thanks very much @Buzinas :) Also OP, for more information on "variable hoisting" as it's called, see [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Thanks for the article too @JonathanBrooks